# Another kind of str_replace() (more strict)

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

***UPDATE : Thank you all for all answers ! I've found another way to solve my problem thanks to your replies !

---

```
        $find = array('ACH', 'AER', 'AERG', 'AGL', 'AIRE', 'ALL', 'ANGL', 'ARC', 'ART', 'AUT', 'AV', 'BASE', 'BD', 'BER', 'BORD', 'BRE', 'BRG', 'BRTL', 'BSN', 'CAE','CALL', 'CAMI', 'CAMP', 'CAN', 'CAR', 'CARE', 'CASR', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF', 'CHA', 'CHE', 'CHEM', 'CHL', 'CHP', 'CHS', 'CHT', 'CHV', 'CITE', 'CIVE','CLOS', 'CLR', 'COIN', 'COL', 'COR', 'CORO', 'COTE', 'COUR', 'CPG', 'CR', 'CRS', 'CRX','CTR', 'CTRE', 'DARS', 'DEVI', 'DIG', 'DOM', 'DRA', 'DSC', 'ECA', 'ECL', 'EMBR', 'EMP', 'ENC', 'ENV', 'ESC', 'ESP', 'ESPA', 'ETNG', 'FD', 'FG','FON', 'FOR', 'FORT', 'FOS', 'FRM', 'GAL', 'GARE', 'GBD', 'GPL', 'GR', 'GREV', 'HAB', 'HAM', 'HIP', 'HLE', 'HLG', 'HLM', 'HTR', 'ILE', 'ILOT', 'IMP', 'JARD', 'JTE', 'LAC', 'LEVE','LICE', 'LIGN', 'LOT', 'MAIL', 'MAIS', 'MAR', 'MARE', 'MAS', 'MNE', 'MRN', 'MTE', 'NTE', 'PAE', 'PARC', 'PAS', 'PASS', 'PCH', 'PCHE', 'PHAR', 'PIST','PKG', 'PL', 'PLA', 'PLAG', 'PLAN', 'PLCI', 'PLE', 'PLN', 'PLT', 'PNT', 'PONT', 'PORQ', 'PORT', 'POST', 'POT', 'PROM', 'PRT', 'PRV', 'PTA', 'PTE', 'PTR', 'PTTE', 'QUA', 'QUAI', 'RAC', 'REM', 'RES','RIVE', 'RLE', 'ROC', 'RPE', 'RPT', 'RTD', 'RTE', 'RUE', 'RUET', 'RUIS', 'RULT', 'RVE', 'SAS', 'SEN', 'SQ', 'STDE', 'TER', 'TOUR', 'TPL', 'TRA','TRAB', 'TRN', 'TRT', 'TSSE', 'TUN', 'VAL', 'VALL', 'VC', 'VCHE', 'VEN', 'VGE', 'VIA','VIAD', 'VIL', 'VLA', 'VOIE', 'VOIR', 'VOUT', 'VOY', 'VTE', 'ZA', 'ZAC', 'ZAD', 'ZI', 'ZONE', 'ZUP');

    $replace = array('ANCIEN CHEMIN', 'AERODROME', 'AEROGARE', 'AGGLOMERATION', 'AIRE', 'ALLEE', 'ANGLE', 'ARCADE', 'ANCIENNE ROUTE', 'AUTOROUTE', 'AVENUE', 'BASE', 'BOULEVARD', 'BERGE', 'BORD', 'BARRIERE', 'BOURG', 'BRETELLE', 'BASSIN', 'CARRIERA', 'CALLE, CALLADA', 'CAMIN', 'CAMP', 'CANAL', 'CARREFOUR', 'CARRIERE', 'CASERNE', 'CHEMIN COMMUNAL', 'CHEMIN DEPARTEMENTAL', 'CHEMIN FORESTIER', 'CHASSE', 'CHEMIN', 'CHEMINEMENT', 'CHALET', 'CHAMP', 'CHAUSSEE', 'CHATEAU', 'CHEMIN VICINAL', 'CITE', 'COURSIVE','CLOS', 'COULOIR', 'COIN', 'COL', 'CORNICHE', 'CORON', 'COTE', 'COUR', 'CAMPING', 'CHEMIN RURAL', 'COURS', 'CROIX','CONTOUR', 'CENTRE', 'DARSE, DARCE', 'DEVIATION', 'DIGUE', 'DOMAINE', 'DRAILLE', 'DESCENTE', 'ECART', 'ECLUSE', 'EMBRANCHEMENT', 'EMPLACEMENT', 'ENCLOS', 'ENCLAVE', 'ESCALIER', 'ESPLANADE', 'ESPACE', 'ETANG', 'FOND', 'FAUBOURG','FONTAINE', 'FORET', 'FORT', 'FOSSE', 'FERME', 'GALERIE', 'GARE', 'GRAND BOULEVARD', 'GRANDE PLACE', 'GRANDE RUE', 'GREVE', 'HABITATION', 'HAMEAU', 'HIPPODROME', 'HALLE', 'HALAGE', 'HLM', 'HAUTEUR', 'ILE', 'ILOT', 'IMPASSE', 'JARDIN', 'JETEE', 'LAC', 'LEVEE', 'LICES','LIGNE', 'LOTISSEMENT', 'MAIL', 'MAISON', 'MARCHE', 'MARE', 'MAS', 'MORNE', 'MARINA', 'MONTEE', 'NOUVELLE ROUTE', 'PETITE AVENUE', 'PARC', 'PASSAGE', 'PASSE', 'PETIT CHEMIN', 'PORCHE', 'PHARE', 'PISTE', 'PARKING','PLACE', 'PLACA', 'PLAGE', 'PLAN', 'PLACIS', 'PASSERELLE', 'PLAINE', 'PLATEAU', 'POINTE', 'PONT', 'PORTIQUE', 'PORT', 'POSTE', 'POTERNE', 'PROMENADE', 'PETITE ROUTE', 'PARVIS', 'PETITE ALLEE', 'PORTE', 'PETITE RUE', 'PLACETTE', 'QUARTIER', 'QUAI', 'RACCOURCI', 'REMPART', 'RESIDENCE','RIVE', 'RUELLE', 'ROCADE', 'RAMPE', 'ROND-POINT', 'ROTONDE', 'ROUTE', 'RUE', 'RUETTE', 'RUISSEAU', 'RUELLETTE', 'RAVINE', 'SAS', 'SENTIER, SENTE', 'SQUARE', 'STADE', 'TERRE', 'TOUR', 'TERRE-PLEIN', 'TRAVERSE','TRABOULE', 'TERRAIN', 'TERTRE', 'TERRASSE', 'TUNNEL', 'VAL', 'VALLON, VALLEE', 'VOIE COMMUNALE', 'VIEUX CHEMIN', 'VENELLE', 'VILLAGE', 'VIA','VIADUC', 'VILLE', 'VILLA', 'VOIE', 'VOIRIE', 'VOUTE', 'VOYEUL', 'VIEILLE ROUTE', 'ZA', 'ZAC', 'ZAD', 'ZI', 'ZONE', 'ZUP');

    $arr = array_combine($find, $replace);

    foreach ($resultat as $enreg) { // extrait chaque ligne une à une
        echo $arr[$enreg['nature']];
    }
```

Have a nice day everyone ;)

---

In my code I need to replace Abbreviations by the real terms.

I currently use a str_replace with arrays to find abbreviations to be change with real terms, here is my code :

```
        foreach ($resultat as $enreg) {
        $enreg['nature'] = str_replace(
            array('ACH', 'AER', 'AERG', 'AGL', 'AIRE', 'ALL', 'ANGL', 'ARC', 'ART', 'AUT', 'AV', 'BASE', 'BD', 'BER', 'BORD', 'BRE', 'BRG', 'BRTL', 'BSN', 'CAE','CALL', 'CAMI', 'CAMP', 'CAN', 'CAR', 'CARE', 'CASR', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF', 'CHA', 'CHE', 'CHEM', 'CHL', 'CHP', 'CHS', 'CHT', 'CHV', 'CITE', 'CIVE','CLOS', 'CLR', 'COIN', 'COL', 'COR', 'CORO', 'COTE', 'COUR', 'CPG', 'CR', 'CRS', 'CRX','CTR', 'CTRE', 'DARS', 'DEVI', 'DIG', 'DOM', 'DRA', 'DSC', 'ECA', 'ECL', 'EMBR', 'EMP', 'ENC', 'ENV', 'ESC', 'ESP', 'ESPA', 'ETNG', 'FD', 'FG','FON', 'FOR', 'FORT', 'FOS', 'FRM', 'GAL', 'GARE', 'GBD', 'GPL', 'GR', 'GREV', 'HAB', 'HAM', 'HIP', 'HLE', 'HLG', 'HLM', 'HTR', 'ILE', 'ILOT', 'IMP', 'JARD', 'JTE', 'LAC', 'LEVE','LICE', 'LIGN', 'LOT', 'MAIL', 'MAIS', 'MAR', 'MARE', 'MAS', 'MNE', 'MRN', 'MTE', 'NTE', 'PAE', 'PARC', 'PAS', 'PASS', 'PCH', 'PCHE', 'PHAR', 'PIST','PKG', 'PL', 'PLA', 'PLAG', 'PLAN', 'PLCI', 'PLE', 'PLN', 'PLT', 'PNT', 'PONT', 'PORQ', 'PORT', 'POST', 'POT', 'PROM', 'PRT', 'PRV', 'PTA', 'PTE', 'PTR', 'PTTE', 'QUA', 'QUAI', 'RAC', 'REM', 'RES','RIVE', 'RLE', 'ROC', 'RPE', 'RPT', 'RTD', 'RTE', 'RUE', 'RUET', 'RUIS', 'RULT', 'RVE', 'SAS', 'SEN', 'SQ', 'STDE', 'TER', 'TOUR', 'TPL', 'TRA','TRAB', 'TRN', 'TRT', 'TSSE', 'TUN', 'VAL', 'VALL', 'VC', 'VCHE', 'VEN', 'VGE', 'VIA','VIAD', 'VIL', 'VLA', 'VOIE', 'VOIR', 'VOUT', 'VOY', 'VTE', 'ZA', 'ZAC', 'ZAD', 'ZI', 'ZONE', 'ZUP'),
            array('ANCIEN CHEMIN', 'AERODROME', 'AEROGARE', 'AGGLOMERATION', 'AIRE', 'ALLEE', 'ANGLE', 'ARCADE', 'ANCIENNE ROUTE', 'AUTOROUTE', 'AVENUE', 'BASE', 'BOULEVARD', 'BERGE', 'BORD', 'BARRIERE', 'BOURG', 'BRETELLE', 'BASSIN', 'CARRIERA', 'CALLE, CALLADA', 'CAMIN', 'CAMP', 'CANAL', 'CARREFOUR', 'CARRIERE', 'CASERNE', 'CHEMIN COMMUNAL', 'CHEMIN DEPARTEMENTAL', 'CHEMIN FORESTIER', 'CHASSE', 'CHEMIN', 'CHEMINEMENT', 'CHALET', 'CHAMP', 'CHAUSSEE', 'CHATEAU', 'CHEMIN VICINAL', 'CITE', 'COURSIVE','CLOS', 'COULOIR', 'COIN', 'COL', 'CORNICHE', 'CORON', 'COTE', 'COUR', 'CAMPING', 'CHEMIN RURAL', 'COURS', 'CROIX','CONTOUR', 'CENTRE', 'DARSE, DARCE', 'DEVIATION', 'DIGUE', 'DOMAINE', 'DRAILLE', 'DESCENTE', 'ECART', 'ECLUSE', 'EMBRANCHEMENT', 'EMPLACEMENT', 'ENCLOS', 'ENCLAVE', 'ESCALIER', 'ESPLANADE', 'ESPACE', 'ETANG', 'FOND', 'FAUBOURG','FONTAINE', 'FORET', 'FORT', 'FOSSE', 'FERME', 'GALERIE', 'GARE', 'GRAND BOULEVARD', 'GRANDE PLACE', 'GRANDE RUE', 'GREVE', 'HABITATION', 'HAMEAU', 'HIPPODROME', 'HALLE', 'HALAGE', 'HLM', 'HAUTEUR', 'ILE', 'ILOT', 'IMPASSE', 'JARDIN', 'JETEE', 'LAC', 'LEVEE', 'LICES','LIGNE', 'LOTISSEMENT', 'MAIL', 'MAISON', 'MARCHE', 'MARE', 'MAS', 'MORNE', 'MARINA', 'MONTEE', 'NOUVELLE ROUTE', 'PETITE AVENUE', 'PARC', 'PASSAGE', 'PASSE', 'PETIT CHEMIN', 'PORCHE', 'PHARE', 'PISTE', 'PARKING','PLACE', 'PLACA', 'PLAGE', 'PLAN', 'PLACIS', 'PASSERELLE', 'PLAINE', 'PLATEAU', 'POINTE', 'PONT', 'PORTIQUE', 'PORT', 'POSTE', 'POTERNE', 'PROMENADE', 'PETITE ROUTE', 'PARVIS', 'PETITE ALLEE', 'PORTE', 'PETITE RUE', 'PLACETTE', 'QUARTIER', 'QUAI', 'RACCOURCI', 'REMPART', 'RESIDENCE','RIVE', 'RUELLE', 'ROCADE', 'RAMPE', 'ROND-POINT', 'ROTONDE', 'ROUTE', 'RUE', 'RUETTE', 'RUISSEAU', 'RUELLETTE', 'RAVINE', 'SAS', 'SENTIER, SENTE', 'SQUARE', 'STADE', 'TERRE', 'TOUR', 'TERRE-PLEIN', 'TRAVERSE','TRABOULE', 'TERRAIN', 'TERTRE', 'TERRASSE', 'TUNNEL', 'VAL', 'VALLON, VALLEE', 'VOIE COMMUNALE', 'VIEUX CHEMIN', 'VENELLE', 'VILLAGE', 'VIA','VIADUC', 'VILLE', 'VILLA', 'VOIE', 'VOIRIE', 'VOUTE', 'VOYEUL', 'VIEILLE ROUTE', 'ZA', 'ZAC', 'ZAD', 'ZI', 'ZONE', 'ZUP'),
            $enreg['nature']
        );
        echo $enreg['nature'];        };
```

The problem here is that str_replace is not strict enough with the abbreviation 'PL' because it will be replaced with 'PLACE' AND with 'PLACA', because 'PL' is in the 'PLA' abbreviation too ...

How can I make a str_replace that would only replace abbreviation with a more strict research (replace 'PL' for 'PLACE' and not for 'PLACACE' because 'PL' is in 'PLA' abbreviation too, for example)?

Comment: You could use a table which stores the abbreviation and what it referes to

Comment: Is your entire site in capital letters?

Comment: Take a look at `preg_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php this can accept arrays for the patterns and the replacements

Comment: @Mecadie the redundancies are more numerous than I first thought.  See for yourself:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f71158e96fbe622f57f6085930b0f0419dfc0bb4

Comment: @RMcLeod the OP knows about the `preg_replace()` function, it is in the question's tag set.  Please delete your comment.

Comment: @Mecadie The question from Lawrence is a relevant one.  We need to see some sample strings to better understand the data being handled.  As Wiktor mentioned in his answer, the solution can be simplified if only the abbreviations in the string are "all-uppercase".  However, if all of the letters in the string are uppercase, then the more verbose pattern from Wiktor with wordboundaries is necessary.  Please include 1 or 2 sample input strings in your question (via an Edit) for clarity.

Comment: Not an answer, but « en français, il est nécessaire de mettre les accents sur les majuscules », « A**É**RODROME », « AGGLOM**É**RATION » ...

Answer (score 1):

You may create an alternation based regex out of the abbreviation values and use word boundaries to only match them in text as whole words, and use a `preg_replace_callback` where you can replace each match with the corresponding replacement value. It will be more convenient if you create an array where your abbreviations will be keys and the replacements will be values (use `array_combine` for this purpose).

The suggest solution might look like

```
$find = array('ACH', 'AER', 'AERG', 'AGL', 'AIRE', 'ALL', 'ANGL', 'ARC', 'ART', 'AUT', 'AV', 'BASE', 'BD', 'BER', 'BORD', 'BRE', 'BRG', 'BRTL', 'BSN', 'CAE','CALL', 'CAMI', 'CAMP', 'CAN', 'CAR', 'CARE', 'CASR', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF', 'CHA', 'CHE', 'CHEM', 'CHL', 'CHP', 'CHS', 'CHT', 'CHV', 'CITE', 'CIVE','CLOS', 'CLR', 'COIN', 'COL', 'COR', 'CORO', 'COTE', 'COUR', 'CPG', 'CR', 'CRS', 'CRX','CTR', 'CTRE', 'DARS', 'DEVI', 'DIG', 'DOM', 'DRA', 'DSC', 'ECA', 'ECL', 'EMBR', 'EMP', 'ENC', 'ENV', 'ESC', 'ESP', 'ESPA', 'ETNG', 'FD', 'FG','FON', 'FOR', 'FORT', 'FOS', 'FRM', 'GAL', 'GARE', 'GBD', 'GPL', 'GR', 'GREV', 'HAB', 'HAM', 'HIP', 'HLE', 'HLG', 'HLM', 'HTR', 'ILE', 'ILOT', 'IMP', 'JARD', 'JTE', 'LAC', 'LEVE','LICE', 'LIGN', 'LOT', 'MAIL', 'MAIS', 'MAR', 'MARE', 'MAS', 'MNE', 'MRN', 'MTE', 'NTE', 'PAE', 'PARC', 'PAS', 'PASS', 'PCH', 'PCHE', 'PHAR', 'PIST','PKG', 'PL', 'PLA', 'PLAG', 'PLAN', 'PLCI', 'PLE', 'PLN', 'PLT', 'PNT', 'PONT', 'PORQ', 'PORT', 'POST', 'POT', 'PROM', 'PRT', 'PRV', 'PTA', 'PTE', 'PTR', 'PTTE', 'QUA', 'QUAI', 'RAC', 'REM', 'RES','RIVE', 'RLE', 'ROC', 'RPE', 'RPT', 'RTD', 'RTE', 'RUE', 'RUET', 'RUIS', 'RULT', 'RVE', 'SAS', 'SEN', 'SQ', 'STDE', 'TER', 'TOUR', 'TPL', 'TRA','TRAB', 'TRN', 'TRT', 'TSSE', 'TUN', 'VAL', 'VALL', 'VC', 'VCHE', 'VEN', 'VGE', 'VIA','VIAD', 'VIL', 'VLA', 'VOIE', 'VOIR', 'VOUT', 'VOY', 'VTE', 'ZA', 'ZAC', 'ZAD', 'ZI', 'ZONE', 'ZUP');
$replace = array('ANCIEN CHEMIN', 'AERODROME', 'AEROGARE', 'AGGLOMERATION', 'AIRE', 'ALLEE', 'ANGLE', 'ARCADE', 'ANCIENNE ROUTE', 'AUTOROUTE', 'AVENUE', 'BASE', 'BOULEVARD', 'BERGE', 'BORD', 'BARRIERE', 'BOURG', 'BRETELLE', 'BASSIN', 'CARRIERA', 'CALLE, CALLADA', 'CAMIN', 'CAMP', 'CANAL', 'CARREFOUR', 'CARRIERE', 'CASERNE', 'CHEMIN COMMUNAL', 'CHEMIN DEPARTEMENTAL', 'CHEMIN FORESTIER', 'CHASSE', 'CHEMIN', 'CHEMINEMENT', 'CHALET', 'CHAMP', 'CHAUSSEE', 'CHATEAU', 'CHEMIN VICINAL', 'CITE', 'COURSIVE','CLOS', 'COULOIR', 'COIN', 'COL', 'CORNICHE', 'CORON', 'COTE', 'COUR', 'CAMPING', 'CHEMIN RURAL', 'COURS', 'CROIX','CONTOUR', 'CENTRE', 'DARSE, DARCE', 'DEVIATION', 'DIGUE', 'DOMAINE', 'DRAILLE', 'DESCENTE', 'ECART', 'ECLUSE', 'EMBRANCHEMENT', 'EMPLACEMENT', 'ENCLOS', 'ENCLAVE', 'ESCALIER', 'ESPLANADE', 'ESPACE', 'ETANG', 'FOND', 'FAUBOURG','FONTAINE', 'FORET', 'FORT', 'FOSSE', 'FERME', 'GALERIE', 'GARE', 'GRAND BOULEVARD', 'GRANDE PLACE', 'GRANDE RUE', 'GREVE', 'HABITATION', 'HAMEAU', 'HIPPODROME', 'HALLE', 'HALAGE', 'HLM', 'HAUTEUR', 'ILE', 'ILOT', 'IMPASSE', 'JARDIN', 'JETEE', 'LAC', 'LEVEE', 'LICES','LIGNE', 'LOTISSEMENT', 'MAIL', 'MAISON', 'MARCHE', 'MARE', 'MAS', 'MORNE', 'MARINA', 'MONTEE', 'NOUVELLE ROUTE', 'PETITE AVENUE', 'PARC', 'PASSAGE', 'PASSE', 'PETIT CHEMIN', 'PORCHE', 'PHARE', 'PISTE', 'PARKING','PLACE', 'PLACA', 'PLAGE', 'PLAN', 'PLACIS', 'PASSERELLE', 'PLAINE', 'PLATEAU', 'POINTE', 'PONT', 'PORTIQUE', 'PORT', 'POSTE', 'POTERNE', 'PROMENADE', 'PETITE ROUTE', 'PARVIS', 'PETITE ALLEE', 'PORTE', 'PETITE RUE', 'PLACETTE', 'QUARTIER', 'QUAI', 'RACCOURCI', 'REMPART', 'RESIDENCE','RIVE', 'RUELLE', 'ROCADE', 'RAMPE', 'ROND-POINT', 'ROTONDE', 'ROUTE', 'RUE', 'RUETTE', 'RUISSEAU', 'RUELLETTE', 'RAVINE', 'SAS', 'SENTIER, SENTE', 'SQUARE', 'STADE', 'TERRE', 'TOUR', 'TERRE-PLEIN', 'TRAVERSE','TRABOULE', 'TERRAIN', 'TERTRE', 'TERRASSE', 'TUNNEL', 'VAL', 'VALLON, VALLEE', 'VOIE COMMUNALE', 'VIEUX CHEMIN', 'VENELLE', 'VILLAGE', 'VIA','VIADUC', 'VILLE', 'VILLA', 'VOIE', 'VOIRIE', 'VOUTE', 'VOYEUL', 'VIEILLE ROUTE', 'ZA', 'ZAC', 'ZAD', 'ZI', 'ZONE', 'ZUP');
$arr = array_combine($find, $replace);
$enreg = "Some PL here";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b(?:'.implode("|", $find) . ')\b/', function($m) use ($arr) {
    return $arr[$m[0]];
}, $enreg);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/9UfQSS).

The `'\b(?:'.implode("|", $find) . ')\b'` will result in a pattern like `\b(?:ACH|AER|AERG|PL|PLA|etc)\b` and will only match the alternatives as whole words.

Note that this solution assumes the abbreviations only consist of letters (word chars), and that your abbreviation list is not too large to fit a single regex pattern. Else, you could use a more generic pattern like `'/\b[A-Z]+\b/'` and inside the callback function, you would need to check if the array contains the found key (e.g. using `isset($arr[$m[0]]`).

Answer (score -1):

You could use a key => value array to do this. Just use the abbreviation as your key, and the full word as the value. Like this:

```
foreach($resultstat as $enreg) {
    $dictionary = [
      'ACH' => 'ANCIEN CHEMIN',
      'AER' => 'AERODROME'
      // and so on
    ];
    echo $dictionary[$enreg];
}
```

Comment: Declare the lookup inside the loop, eh?   I don't think so.

Comment: Your text says you can use key => value but your code does not mention key at all. And not sure how this will solve OPs problem